# Bullet passes through the player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using unity and when the enemy shoots, the bullet passes right threw the player. I don't know how to solve this. Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
private Transform player;
private Vector2 target;
private Vector2 moveDirection;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    moveDirection = (player.transform.position - transform.position).normalized * speed;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y);
    //transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

I put a tag named BulletEnemy on the bullet but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have colliders on both the bullet and the player? Is  `IsTrigger` enabled on any of these colliders?

Comment: Are you sure that you assigned the tag Player to the player game object?

Answer (score 0):

How fast is your speed value?

At high speeds a bullet might move farther in one frame than the depth of the object you want it to hit. You can still detect collisions by every frame storing the position of your bullet as a vector and on the next frame casting a ray between the current position and the last known position in the previous frame. If the ray hits your enemy then call the same function that you would on a physics collision.

There is no way to do it with only OnCollisionEnter because of the effect of bullet speed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your bullet's speed. if they are too fast, your physics engine just ignore the collision and therefore no `OnCollisionEnter` will be called.
2. Use larger `Collider` for your player. and also check `Player` tag on your player object. also make sure your tagged object has `Collider2D` component.
3. Change `OnCollisionEnter2D` to `OnCollisionStay2D`. if you want to Destroy bullet, there will be no difference in runtime